# How to find the source file that generate VM Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, event-handling

My Rails application generate incorrect JS VM Script as circled that cause a issue.

**How can I track to the source that generate it?** (Source JS that created it not the displayed one in screenshots)

[image]

I've check on Firefox but issue still occured with different file name.

[image]

FYI

I found this issue when I deployed this service into production in AWS EC2 only.

Start the service in local got no issue

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL DR;

Use Network tab to inspect suspecious call which cause additional VM_____ script.

I've inspect and check Network

There's a xhr called inside some widget

That **xhr call this appilication script again** as eval function

So all resource in this page loaded twice

[image]

I've disable that JS and it's work now.

There's no additional VM____ in the inspection anymore